# bash script - if statement with grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

Preface that I am new to bash scripting and attempting to parse a log file and output the info I am looking for into a txt file.

I have got a start to my script, however I am now stuck with a condition statement. I'm not sure grep is the best use case now, perhaps awk or sed.

contents of file example:

```
2022-1-3 14:00:00 ERROR THREAD234 - error info here 
2022-1-4 02:00:00 WARNI THREAD235 - warning info here 
additional warning info here, sometimes includes word error, but i do not want to capture this additional line as it is a warning
2022-2-3 01:00:00 ERROR THREAD333 - error info here2 
error info continued, sometimes there are multiple lines to an error and they do not all include the word error. however, these additional lines to do not include date/times. these are typically stack traces. 
2023-3-4 11:00:00 INFO0 THREAD333 - info here
2022-2-5 01:00:00 ERROR THREAD333 - error info here3
2022-2-6 06:00:00 ERROR THREAD333 - error info here3
```

desired output:

```
1 ERORR - error info here
1 ERROR - error info here2
error info contined, sometimes includes a tab at the beginning of this line and sometimes does not
2 ERROR - error info here3
```

current output:

```
1 ERORR - error info here
1 ERROR - error info here2
2 ERROR - error info here3
```

My end goal:
I am trying to only grab the errors and their following line if it is continuing information on that error. My thought is to use a conditional if. If the next line from ERROR does not start with a date, then print. If it does, only print the error.

I do not want to include the date, time, or thread in my output and do not want errors info to repeat themselves in the output.

Currently where I'm at with the bash script, it does work but I need to fine tune it with the condition to include next line if the error is continuing.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "File path to log, no spaces: " file
outputFile=Desktop/errorOutput.txt
error=$(grep ERROR $file | cut -b 25-32,47-1000 | sort | uniq -c)
touch $outputFile
echo "$error" > $outputFile
cat $outputFile
```

I'm attempted an if statement for the grep, however the logic is flawed. I'm currently attempting to figure it out with awk instead.

Comment: @Cyrus thank you, I've entered desired output and my current output, the number at the beginning of the desired output is due to the uniq -c,

Comment: so the "extra" line (`error info continued....`) may not contain the word error? Best to remove that from your sample data. People will just recommend `grep -i error logFile > errors`. You will need to develop a "rule" about what "extra" data should be kept and what can be discarded. Does "any line without a time-stamp" count as an "extra" errror to include? And **yes**, `awk` is designed to solve such problems. Focus your work there. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter correct, the additional line may not include the word error and sometimes warnings and infos have additional lines too, I will update my example file accordingly and continue to look into awk. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution using GNU AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:digit:]-]+ [[:digit:]:]+ "; ORS=""
           PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}
     /ERROR/ {gsub("THREAD.* -", "-", $0); !a[$0]++} 
     END{for (i in a) {print a[i], i}}' logfile
1 ERROR - error info here
1 ERROR - error info here2
error info continued, sometimes there are multiple lines to an error and they do not all include the word error. however, these additional lines to do not include date/times. these are typically stack traces.
2 ERROR - error info here3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby that does that:

```
ruby -e '
$<.read.scan(/(ERROR[\s\S]*?)(?=^\d{4}|\z)/).  # find the error to next date
    flatten(1).                                # remove one match level
    map(&:strip).                              # remove " \n" at end
    map{|e| e.sub(/^(ERROR\s+)[^-]+/,"\\1")}.  # remove THREAD part
    group_by{|e| e[/ERROR\s+-\s+.*$/]}.        # group by error tag
    map{|k,v| puts "#{v.length} #{v[0]}"}         # print them
' file
```

Prints:

```
1 ERROR - error info here
1 ERROR - error info here2 
error info continued, sometimes there are multiple lines to an error and they do not all include the word error. however, these additional lines to do not include date/times. these are typically stack traces.
2 ERROR - error info here3
```